# if statement to see if a Form checkbox is checked from a regular module

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if Userform Checkbox is checked but my code is in a regular module not userform.  Please suggest how to do this correctly? Or does this only works from a userform module?

`if Userform1.Checkbox1 = True 'checkbox is checked`  //compile error observed

Thank you

Comment: You're missing a `Then` on the end of that line.

Comment: If Thank you Then thank you end thank you :)